# Is there a more efficient/less time demanding way to change this matrix size?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, resize

Let's consider my Matlab code:

```
T = 250;
N = 10;
B = 5000;

% starting matrix
Matrix1 = rand(T,N*3,B);
% ending matrix
Matrix2 = nan(T,B*3,N);

% the loop is very slow
for n = 1:(N*3)
    for b = 1:B
        if n <= 10
            Matrix2(:,b,n) = Matrix1(:,n,b);
        elseif n <= 20
            Matrix2(:,b + B,n - N) = Matrix1(:,n,b);
        else
            Matrix2(:,b + B + B,n - N - N) = Matrix1(:,n,b);
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any more efficient or less time consuming way to get to the second matrix?

Comment: Should all of the "Matrix1" variables on the left side of the assignments be "Matrix2"?

Comment: Not a final good solution (that would involve `reshape` probably, maybe just `reshape`, actually, but your if/elses are basically `Matrix2(:, b*(i-1)*B+1, n*(i-1)*N+1)`, for any number of splits, in this case, 3.

Comment: Assigning into the right matrix might make this code a bit faster. But you can probably do this in one go with `reshape` and `permute`, or otherwise copy over the three blocks separately. There certainly is no need to loop over `n` and `b` like this.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome yess all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The loop can written as a combination of `reshape` and `permute` operations:

```
Matrix2 = reshape(permute(reshape(Matrix1, T,N,3,B), [1 4 3 2]), T, B*3, N);
```

The primary answer can be useful for converting the loop to vectorized form:

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
n = 1:(N*3);
b = 1:B;
% split n based on 3 conditions
n1 = n(n <= 10);
n2 = n(n > 10 & n <= 20);
n3 = n(n > 20);
% the order of dimensions of both arrays should match
Matrix11 = permute(Matrix1, [1,3,2]);

Matrix2(:, b, n1) = Matrix11(:, b, n1); 
Matrix2(:, b + B, n2 - N) = Matrix11(:, b, n2);
Matrix2(:, b + B + B, n3 - N - N) = Matrix11(:, b, n3);
```

The index `n` should be divided into three parts based on the three conditions. Also it is required to permute `Matrix1` so its order of dimensions matches the order of `Matrix2` to ensure that the vectorized assignment works correctly. However because the order of dimensions of `Matrix1` is changed it is required to reorder the index positions when extracting subsets of `Matrix11`.

Equivalently `permute` can be applied per assignment

```
n = 1:(N*3);
b = 1:B;

n1 = n(n <= 10);
n2 = n(n > 10 & n <= 20);
n3 = n(n > 20);

Matrix2(:, b, n1) = permute(Matrix1(:, n1, b),[1 3 2]); 
Matrix2(:, b + B, n2 - N) = permute(Matrix1(:, n2, b),[1 3 2]);
Matrix2(:, b + B + B, n3 - N - N) = permute(Matrix1(:, n3, b),[1 3 2]);
```